# createbundle fails with `file.parentFile must not be null`

Tags: install4j

I want to create a JRE bundle from a Zulu JDK.
Steps:

- Downloaded `zulu11.41.24-sa-jdk11.0.8-win_i686.zip`
- Unzipped it, giving me a `zulu11.41.24-sa-jdk11.0.8-win_i686` directory.
- Ran `createbundle`, which failed, transcript following:

```
C:\develop\projects\id-gui\target\downloads\jre-bundles>..\install4j8.0.8\bin\createbundle.exe zulu11.41.24-sa-jdk11.0.8-win_i686
java.lang.IllegalStateException: file.parentFile must not be null
        at com.install4j.jdk.v.l(ejt:102)
        at com.install4j.jdk.v.c(ejt:94)
        at com.install4j.b.a.a.run(ejt:44)
        at com.install4j.CreateBundleApplication.n(ejt:93)
        at com.install4j.CreateBundleApplication.main(ejt:205)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:84)
        at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
        at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)

There was an error when writing the JRE bundle
The error message was: file.parentFile must not be null
```

What does that error message mean, and how to I get `createbundle` past that hurdle?
(I did create JRE bundles sucessfully in the past, this failure comes unexpected.)

Answer (score 1):

Passing a relative path to `createbundle` leads to this failure. This will be fixed in install4j 8.0.9.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I could solve this by cd'ing to the directory where createbundle lives:

```
C:\develop\projects\id-gui\target\downloads\install4j8.0.8\bin>createbundle ..\..\jre-bundles\zulu11.41.24-sa-jdk11.0.8-win_i686
Linking JRE
Writing JRE bundle archive....................................................................................................
The bundle file C:\develop\projects\id-gui\target\downloads\install4j8.0.8\bin\windows-x86-11.0.8.tar.gz was successfully created.
```

Looks like a bug in createbundle.

Comment: Can you try specifying an absolute path to createbundle (without cd'ing into the bin directory) and check if that works?

Comment: Sure. It fails: `C:\develop\projects\id-gui\target\downloads\jre-bundles>C:\develop\projects\id-gui\target\downloads\install4j8.0.8\bin\createbundle.exe zulu11.41.24-sa-jdk11.0.8-win_i686` gives `java.lang.IllegalStateException: file.parentFile must not be null`

Comment: Sorry, I actually meant passing an absolute path instead of `zulu11.41.24-sa-jdk11.0.8-win_i686`

Comment: I tested with an absolute path for executable and source JDK, and that indeed works.

Comment: Using a relative path for the executable and an absolute for the JDK works, too.

Comment: Aside note: It does not seem to work inside Cygwin. It complains that `\cygdrive\c\Users\tkd6u\projects\id-gui\target\downloads\jre-bundles\zulu11.41.24-sa-jdk11.0.8-win_i686` does not exist. (It would be nice to have a `createbundle.exe` that can run inside Cygwin, but I know this can be difficult in code, so maybe we'll have to live with that paper cut.)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, we will fix this in 8.0.9.